# Create tabs in a matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, tabs

How can I create tabs in matlab gui?
I did something like this a while ago...
I mean I created some menus at top of my GUI and then pressing each menu will set visible property of some controls on and the others get off
that way is useful for small GUIs but in beag GUIs it encounters problems and editing the GUI gets hard
I need someway to create seperate GUIs acting just like Mozilla tabs
Is there anyway to create that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tabs aren't officially supported yet, even though there exists the semi-documented function [uitab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/tab-panels-uitab-and-relatives/). Note that in 2012a it warns you that the function will change.

However, there is a very nice submission on the File Exchange, the [GUI layout toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox) that comes with tab functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab supports tabs from R2014b

See [uitabgroup](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitabgroup.html)