# How do I create a tabbed GUI in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, tabs

I want to create a tabbed GUI in which first tab is for reading input, then the input is displayed on the GUI.  The User should be able to select the data from GUI and then given as input to a algorithm. Also the user can select parameters for the algortihm in another tab. In the third tab,  the user can see the resulting plots.

How do I create a tabbed GUI within MatLab either programmatically or using the GUIDE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859739/create-tabs-in-a-matlab-gui

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a simple example using the semi-documented function UITAB to create tabs:

```
function tabbedGUI()
    %# create tabbed GUI
    hFig = figure('Menubar','none');
    s = warning('off', 'MATLAB:uitabgroup:OldVersion');
    hTabGroup = uitabgroup('Parent',hFig);
    warning(s);
    hTabs(1) = uitab('Parent',hTabGroup, 'Title','Data');
    hTabs(2) = uitab('Parent',hTabGroup, 'Title','Params');
    hTabs(3) = uitab('Parent',hTabGroup, 'Title','Plot');
    set(hTabGroup, 'SelectedTab',hTabs(1));

    %# populate tabs with UI components
    uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'String','Load data...', ...
        'Parent',hTabs(1), 'Callback',@loadButtonCallback);
    uicontrol('Style','popupmenu', 'String','r|g|b', ...
        'Parent',hTabs(2), 'Callback',@popupCallback);
    hAx = axes('Parent',hTabs(3));
    hLine = plot(NaN, NaN, 'Parent',hAx, 'Color','r');

    %# button callback
    function loadButtonCallback(src,evt)
        %# load data
        [fName,pName] = uigetfile('*.mat', 'Load data');
        if pName == 0, return; end
        data = load(fullfile(pName,fName), '-mat', 'X');

        %# plot
        set(hLine, 'XData',data.X(:,1), 'YData',data.X(:,2));

        %# swithc to plot tab
        set(hTabGroup, 'SelectedTab',hTabs(3));
        drawnow
    end

    %# drop-down menu callback
    function popupCallback(src,evt)
        %# update plot color
        val = get(src,'Value');
        clr = {'r' 'g' 'b'};
        set(hLine, 'Color',clr{val})

        %# swithc to plot tab
        set(hTabGroup, 'SelectedTab',hTabs(3));
        drawnow
    end
end
```

[image: tab1]
[image: tab2]
[image: tab3]

Comment: This was outstanding.  Thank you so much for providing this example!

Answer (score 3):

You can also create tabs from a GUIDE created GUI with the help of a utility available from [Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54705-tabmanager-create-tab-panels--uitabgroup--from-a-guide-gui) that I wrote.

The usage is fairly simple:

1. Create a pane with tag set to Tab? where ? is any letter or number (e.g. TabA). This main pane should be left empty and determines the size and location of the tab group (uitabgroup).
2. Create additional panes with a tag name that starts with the name of the main pane. All other controls should be added to these panes.
3. In the Guide generated function xxx_OpeningFcn add the following:

   handles.tabManager = TabManager( hObject );

The location of the additional panes is not important but it is generally easier to edit the GUI if they are in the same location as the main pane.  You can edit the panes even if they are overlaid by cycling through the panes with the "Send to back" command from the Guide pop up menu.

[image: Tab Group Place holder][image: Main Tab]
[image: Supplementary Tab][image: Resulting GUI]

Comment: Hi, just a quick question: playing with the "Send to back" option is the only way to create tabbed gui with GUIDE? I was thinking for the future if I want to add something to one tab and I need to find it in the figure editor. This problem is even worst with many tabs

Comment: @Shika93 - Unfortunately that's the only way that I know of