# How do I embedded another figure within a figure in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm developing a GUI for my MatLab code using UITab and UITabGroup from this previous post:

[How do I create a tabbed GUI in MatLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084565/tabbed-software-in-matlab)

However that code populates each tabs ui within a single function.  Since my user interface is going to be more complicated than that, I'm hoping to create a figure for each tab using it's own function .m file and then import that figure into the main GUI function .m file.  It attempted to do this by returning the figure from the original function to the main gui:

**Tabbed Interface:**

```
function tabbedUI = tab_gui1()
... Code for tabbed UI
end
```

**Main GUI:**

```
function test_embeddedGUI()

    hFig = figure('Menubar', 'none');
    test = tab_gui1(hFig);

    uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'This is a simple test', 'Callback', @testButton);

    function testButton(src, evt)

        disp('button was pressed');
    end
end
```

My problem is that when I create the 'sub figure' it creates a new figure window and doesn't embed it into the main GUI's figure.

[image: :/]

How do I create a figure that can be embedded within another figure?

Comment: I don't understand why you want another figure. Why won't you just reuse an existing axes object, or create a new one?

Comment: @EitanT that was what I assumed needed to happen, however after [chatting it appears](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116/conversation/matlab-tabular-gui) that I just need to pass the parent figure and populate using that?  I'm still not for sure on how to do this exactly and am open to all suggestions.

Comment: @EitanT is probably right, in Python you'd just draw to the axes object too, which is part of the figure object, but the one doing the actual drawing.

Comment: @EitanT you are right (as well as Ivo).  My approach to this was wrong.  I finally figured it out and added my results as an answer.

Comment: @Kronos I've just seen it. But you probably should rewrite it in first person :)

Comment: @EitanT I purposefully answer self posts in the third person to try to help myself, and others delineate between question and answer.  It may be an uncommon approach, but I feel that it helps.

Comment: @KronoS A bit weird, but understandable :)

Comment: KronoS, it looks like you have a solution to your immediate problem. But a piece of advice, if I may - if you're trying to create a GUI of some complexity, particularly if it involves a tabbed interface, you will find it a lot easier if you try out Ben Tordoff's [GUI Layout Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox). Seriously, invest an afternoon playing with it and you will thank me. You'll get proper tabs that don't use the semidocumented `uitab`, you'll get resizing for free, and it's just much more flexible.

Comment: @SamRoberts I've seen that a couple of times now.  I'll check it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating a new a new figure, instead pass the parent object you want to embed the code into.  For example, (assuming you used the linked questions' accepted answer's code):

```
function tab_gui1(parent)
    hTabGroup = uitabgroup('Parent', parent); % parent here is the main GUI figure.
    hTabs(1) = uitab('Parent', hTabGroup, 'Title', 'Data');
    hTabs(2) = uitab('Parent', hTabGroup, 'Title', 'Params');
    hTabs(3) = uitab('Parent', hTabGroup, 'Title', 'Plot');
    set(hTabGroup, 'SelectedTab', hTabs(1));

... Rest of Code is the same

end
```

Then pass the parent object to the sub GUI function:

```
function test_embeddedGUI()
    hFig = figure('Menubar', 'none');
    tab_gui1(hFig);  % your parent object being passed is the main figure.

    uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'This is a simple test', 'Callback', @testButton);
    function testButton(src, evt)
        disp('button was pressed');
    end
end
```

However with this particular arrangement you get elements that can/will overlap:

[image: Overlapping buttons]

Notice that the buttons are overlapping.  From what I can gather from your question, it appears that you want to have a tabular main interface with sub interfaces for each tab.  I suggest creating the tabbed interface on the main GUI and then creating a [uipanel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel.html) for each of those tabs.  You would then populate those uipanels using your separate functions.  Here's a quick example:

**Main UI**

```
function test_embeddedGUI()
    hFig = figure('Menubar', 'none');

    hTabGroup = uitabgroup('Parent', hFig);

    hTabs(1) = uitab('Parent', hTabGroup, 'Title', 'First');
    hTabs(2) = uitab('Parent', hTabGroup, 'Title', 'Second');
    hTabs(3) = uitab('Parent', hTabGroup, 'Title', 'Third');

    set(hTabGroup, 'SelectedTab', hTabs(1));

    firstPanel = uipanel('Title', 'Main Panel', 'Parent', hTabs(1));
    secondPanel = uipanel('Title', 'Secondary Panel', 'Parent', hTabs(2));
    thirdPanel = uipanel('Title', 'Final Panel', 'Parent', hTabs(3));

    subUI1(firstPanel);
end
```

**SubUI:**

```
function subUI1(parent)
    firstButton = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'First Button' ...
        , 'Parent', parent, 'Callback', @buttonPress);

    function buttonPress(src, evt)
        disp('Main Button press');
    end

end
```

Which will create an interface like so:

[image: Yay! Something that works!]